# Como desenvolver no Android Studio com o banco de dados Firebird?

Tags: android, firebird

Não é possível conectar com um banco Firebird externo pelo Android Studio? devo utilizar o eclipse?

Pesquisando muito como fazer esta conexão, vi em alguns posts que o android não consegue fazer esta conexão.

E onde posso baixar o android sdk?

não consigo achar mais para configurar o eclipse para programar com o android.

Comment: o android sdk esta nesse link   la na parte de baixo, ele esta   abaixo do próprio download do android studio...https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: @tahatsu o suporte ao eclipse acabou, o google recomenda que você desenvolva com a IDE Android Studio, mas, é sim possível baixar o SDK e tentar ainda desenvolver com o eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Você pode tentar conectar com o Firebird usando o JDBC específico para isso. O fato de você utilizar o **Eclipse** ou **Android Studio** não muda nada nesse sentido. Portanto pode ser que não funcione.

Utilizo aqui para Firebird, em aplicação WEB o [JayBird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

O SDK do Android pode ser encontrado facilmente numa pesquisa rápida no Google. Se você já tem a SDK baixada de quando usava o Eclipse, você pode apontar para ela nas configurações do Android Studio. Pode ser, provavelmente, que você precise baixar mais componentes, o próprio Android Studio deve solicitar. Mas ai o SDK Manager deve ajudar.

Um exemplo disso pode ser visto nesta questão do SO-En: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583024/1997073

Comment: o problema é que não encontro nada no google sobre fazer esta conexão com banco externo, principalmente sobre firebird, o que encontro não me ajuda muito, talvez eu esteja procurando da forma errada, sei la...

mas de qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção

Comment: @Tahatsu veja que não é interessante você conectar diretamente da aplicação mibile com um banco de dados externo. O correto é você ter uma camada, web-service, que acesse o banco de dados, e seu app acessa essa camada. Alguns links que podem ajudar: http://www.androidpro.com.br/usando-banco-de-dados-externo-no-android/ e http://diegocavalca.com/parte-5-criando-o-aplicativo-mobile-e-integrando-dados-via-api/

Comment: esse primeiro link já havia encontrado, mas essa API é paga então me complicou, o segundo link nunca havia encontrado e me parece que sera de muita ajuda. bom eu encontrei um tutorial no youtube de webservice segue o link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J87qN3B-dI , apesar de ser para mysql estou tentando modificar para usar no firebird, mas o ponto não é este, o ponto é que ao ver este tutorial, fiquei confuso, a web service não é criada dentro do aplicativo android?, tenho que cria-lo separdo e coloca-lo no servidor?, para ai sim criar o app para acessar esta web service?

Comment: fiquei muito confuso vendo este tutorial e uma duvida tenho um sistema em delphi eu posso criar um webservice em java?, não ocorrera conflitos?

Comment: O web-service pode sim ser criado em Java, PHP, ou outra linguagem, e você pode acessá-lo usando o Android, e sim, ele será hospedado em algum lugar. Para mudar de MySQL para Firebird você provavelmente só irá mudar o driver do JDBC. Os links que passei são de tópicos que explicam como usar um web-service, a idéia era servir de base mesmo. Procure outros.